# Loading json from different domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Is there any way to load the json provided by the http://search.twitter.com/search.json URL on to my page via ajax? Everything I've tried gives me:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

If not, then whats the point of having such services in the first place?W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), or JSON with padding:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.getTwitterResults = function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    };
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=cheese&callback=getTwitterResults"></script>
```

Comment: Did not know the callback thing existed.